# Traefik 2.9 with Docker: How to redirect non-www to www without defining the rule globaly

Tags: redirect, traefik, http-redirect

This is my docker-compose.yml for Traefik 2.9.

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.9"
    container_name: "traefik"
    command:
      #- "--log.level=DEBUG"
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
      - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443"
      - "--entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.to=websecure"
      - "--entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.scheme=https"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.httpchallenge=true"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.httpchallenge.entrypoint=web"
      #- "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.caserver=https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.email=test.test@test.com"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - "./letsencrypt:/letsencrypt"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"

networks:
  default:
    name: traefik-network
```

And this is one of my services which I use. I want only for this service that non-www requests will be redirected to www.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - ./code:/code
    depends_on:
      - web
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.ttt.rule=Host(`www.example.com`, `example.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.ttt.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.ttt.tls.certresolver=myresolver"

networks:
  default:
    name: traefik-network
```

Examples:
https://example.com/test/123/ => redirect to => https://www.example.com/test/123/

How can I define this in my second docker-compose.yml?

Comment: Define different routers for www.example.com (1) and example.com (2). On (2) you add a redirect middleware

Comment: Where? On the docker-compose.yml  where nginx is running?

Comment: Yes, on the docker-compose of nginx via traefik labels

Comment: Thank you, creating two different routers solved this problem.